# Clearing form field error classes using jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, jquery-ui

I am validating a form and when there is any error in the textfield or any form element I am adding `error` class to that element. Something like

```
jQuery("#headerSignin_FirstName").addClass('error');
```

There are like 6-7 fields which need to be validated and once validated I want to reset the `error` class being append to the form elements.
Though I can manually use `removeClass` for each field but looking for a more elegant and clear solution to do this.

Comment: @Ajinkya: i agree!! i already accepted answers whose able to solve my problems. will update the rest with solutions.Thanks for reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually using `removeClass` for each field, only select element with `error` class and use `removeClass`

```
$('#form_id .error').removeClass('error');
```

Comment: won't it remove any other outside the form? i only want things for a specific form

Comment: then you can use `$('#form_id .error').removeClass('error')`.

Comment: that again leads me to do it for each and every form field? can't i use something like with respect to form id?

Comment: @user728947: I have used form id only. you dont have to do it for every element.It will remove `error` class from elements within particular form. I think `form_id` is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('input').removeClass('error')
```

or

```
$('input').removeClass('error').addClass('you_can_even_add_another_class');
```

Comment: that is like doing it for each and every form field